# How can I use java.util.Currency in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, currency

I'm working on a GWT application, and we introduced a Money class that contains a java.util.Currency. The only problem is that GWT doesn't seem to support this class.

I did a google search and found [this code](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/changes/jat/numberformat-r2942/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Currency.java?r=2952) in the GWT source code, but I'm not quite sure what the "jat numberformat-r2942" library is, or how to inherit it into my project. Has anybody successfully been able to use this GWT library? If not, what is the best way to deal with currencies in a GWT application?

Should I just capture the currency as a String on the client side, then create a Currency object on the server side? We're trying to use the [GWT-dispatch library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/), so I'd like to use the same bean on the client and server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jat/numberformat-r2942` is not a separate library that can be included via a JAR file. It looks like the `changes` directory in the GWT source repository may be a place to hold individual user's branches containing possible future additions to the mainline GWT source.

If you want to use that implementation of Currency (which may be buggy and/or incomplete) your best bet is to copy it to your source tree (changing the packages for all of the necessary classes) and use `<super-source>` as Peter suggests.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. I tried it and it worked, although my IDE was not happy about having a class with package java.util in the com/xxx/jre/java/util path. I went ahead and created my own Currency value object and a client and server factory that I can look up the currencies using ISO 4217 codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<super-source>` to replace all non-translatable classes with your version.

Take a look at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html, look for "Overriding one package implementation with another".

OTOH, if you only need to transfer this object through GWT-RPC, then use the new [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) that solves this issue altogether - there are no common classes on server and client, proxies are used instead.

Comment: I understand that I can override non-translatable classes, but how do I inherit that particular library so that I don't have to rewrite the code myself? It doesn't seem like its part of the standard emulated set of classes. I don't see any references to a "JAT" jar.